# Get number of +1's for url in android with PlusClient

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-plus-one

So I'm trying to implement a custom +1 button in an android app.

I have the standard PlusOneButton working - it shows the number of +1's but I can't read the number from it. And the PlusClient doesn't seem to have the ability to tell me the number. I tried Google+ REST API but it doesn't have this functionality either.

I know there's some hack that could get the number over a POST call but that already stopped working once and I can't rely on non-official stuff.

So: is there any way to get this number through the standard **google-play-services.jar**?

Also: is there a way to activate a hidden PlusOneButton when the user clicks my custom button? `.performClick()` doesn't work.

Thanks.